# Setting up RAMP UP TIME and delay between requests in JMETER

Tags: jmeter, performance, load-testing

If I set the *number of threads* to 50 and *ramp up time* to 750 - does it mean that 15 users will come on site every second?

If yes then how can I set a delay between users? Because for requests I am using a constant timer to set delay between requests. But how do I set delays between users?

Comment: Number of threads = Number of users ,
Ramp Up Time the time between every Request 'Thread'

Comment: Can you please describe with example? Because I think there is difference between 2 users and 2 requests and I want to set delay in both scenario.

Comment: number of users (called threads)  the Ramp-Up Period, leave the the default value of 1 seconds. This property tells JMeter how long to delay between starting each user. For example, if you enter a Ramp-Up Period of 5 seconds, JMeter will finish starting all of your users by the end of the 5 seconds. So, if we have 5 users and a 5 second Ramp-Up Period, then the delay between starting users would be 1 second (5 users / 5 seconds = 1 user per second).

Comment: ok so if I set no. of users = 50 and ramp up time = 750 then  each user will come to site every 15 seconds , right?

Comment: Yes that it and you can monitor that by adding "View Result in Table" in the Start time column

Comment: okay , thanks a lot... I was confuse in that only..

Comment: @A.Mo5tar and @'Helping Hands', please post the solution and crux of your discussion as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

number of users (called threads) the Ramp-Up Period, leave the the default value of 1 seconds. This property tells JMeter how long to delay between starting each user. For example, if you enter a Ramp-Up Period of 5 seconds, JMeter will finish starting all of your users by the end of the 5 seconds. So, if we have 5 users and a 5 second Ramp-Up Period, then the delay between starting users would be 1 second (5 users / 5 seconds = 1 user per second).
you can monitor that by adding "View Result in Table" in the Start time column

Answer (score 1):

All virtual users defined in "Threads" will be started during the "Ramp-up" time. Divide threads number by ramp-up time to know how many users will be arriving each second. If you don't like what you're seeing you can consider using [Stepping Thread Group](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SteppingThreadGroup/) or [Ultimate Thread Group](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/)

Actually you can just provide enough users and focus on controlling how often they will be sending requests via [Constant Throughput Timer](https://blazemeter.com/throughput-constant-timer) or [Throughput Shaping Timer](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/)

Comment: Thank for detailed answer.. I will try with your suggested timers.